# Changing the CSS of a different element using ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a form with one field and the markup with razor elements looks like below. When i click submit, this shows up the validation error message. However, my requirement is, instead of showing the error message, **i want to change the css of the parent div class from "col-xs-6" to "col-xs-6 has-error"**. Is that possible?

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookingReference,new { @class="form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.BookingReference)
</div>
```

Comment: I would think you would need a bit of JS to dynamically add the `has-error` class to the parent of any element that has the razor validation messages

Answer (score 0):

good sample at jonas stawski page

http://jstawski.com/post/2013/10/08/MVC-Unobtrusive-Validation-with-Twitter-Bootstrap

Comment: A better answer would be to give some background on the problem rather than a simple link.